# Ubuntu 21.04 Nautilus sidebar Desktop icon is missing

Tags: nautilus

It has been asked many times but none of the solutions helped me. I updated from 20.10 and now Nautilus sidebar Desktop icon is missing.

[image]

Here's my **user-dirs.dirs**:

```
# This file is written by xdg-user-dirs-update
# If you want to change or add directories, just edit the line you're
# interested in. All local changes will be retained on the next run.
# Format is XDG_xxx_DIR="$HOME/yyy", where yyy is a shell-escaped
# homedir-relative path, or XDG_xxx_DIR="/yyy", where /yyy is an
# absolute path. No other format is supported.
# 
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Public"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Music"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"
```

I know I can put a bookmark of `desktop` but I don't want that, I just want the desktop back in the prior position.

Comment: How can it have been asked many times before as 21.04 has only just been released. If there is an issue you want to draw the attention o the developers to the file a bug report with Launchpad.

Comment: I mean this sort of question, like desktop icon is missing, But sometimes it shows at some moments particularly at file chooser.

Answer (score 3):

*Update:* [this is a **GTK 3 bug that happens in Wayland** sessions](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+3.0/+bug/1875671), which is now (Ubuntu 21.04) the default display server. When using a X11 session you can still see the folder.

*Original answer:* I'm experiencing the same problem. I tried a lot of things (check *user-dirs.dirs*, exec *xdg-user-dirs-update*, etc) but nothing seems to fix this. I think it's a bug in the Files version distributed with Ubuntu 21.04 (nautilus 1:3.38.2-1ubuntu2) so I [filed a bug in Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1928263).

Comment: Thanks for raising the bug.  I concur that this looks like a Wayland regression as the shortcut does indeed appear when switching the session to X.  For anyone else who's annoyed by this, please make sure to "vote" for the bug by clicking the link at the top left of the page that says: "This bug affects XX people. Does this bug affect you?" (you'll need to sign on to Launchpad).  This way, the bug may get some attention...

Comment: The same bug also exists in 21.10 wayland sessions.

Answer (score 3):

Open the terminal by pressing Ctrl+Shift+t and type `nautilus ~/Desktop`. This will open Nautilus in the Desktop directory (another way is to just search for it at home in Nautilus). If `~/Desktop` doesn't exist, then create a Desktop directory with `touch ~/Desktop`

With Ctrl+d the current directory (Desktop) should be added to the sidebar.

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 22.04 and it's good enough as a fix.

Comment: To me, I needed reinstall it: `sudo apt install --reinstall nautilus` (here, Ubuntu 23.04)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue after upgrading from ubuntu 20.10 to 21.04. My desktop icons were missing. I used the below commands and all the icons were back after restarting.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install gnome-shell ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```