# Home Directory Folders on Desktop

Tags: directory, home-directory

After a hard crash of Ubuntu, the folders in the home directory are appearing on the desktop. How can I remove them?

[Gnome Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iywXl.jpg)

Comment: Hi Tom. Can you please edit the question to include more information. This question requires further clarity. What were you doing? Why do you say it's a hard crash? Any screenshots would be helpful.

Comment: Please add the output of `ls -ldh ~/Desktop`

Comment: The Desktop folder is missing. How can I add a new one?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 21.04 Nautilus sidebar Desktop icon is missing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333565/ubuntu-21-04-nautilus-sidebar-desktop-icon-is-missing)