# Add Desktop bookmark to Nautilus sidebar on Ubuntu 22.04 as it used to be in 18.04 and 20.04

Tags: nautilus, 22.04

I installed Ubuntu 22.04, and I noticed that the 'Desktop' is missing from the Nautilus side bar:
[image]

I would like to insert "Desktop" bookmark between "Home" and "Documents" as it used to be in previous Ubuntu LTS versions:

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Note: I want the bookmark to be in the same location it used to be, i.e. not at the bottom, after the separator.

Comment: Yup, very irritating. Wonder what's the logic for this move.

Answer (score 5):

Just drag your Desktop folder into the nautilus sidebar, You will see a button named 'New Bookmark'. Then place the folder there, and you will see Desktop has been added to the nautilus sidebar.

Comment: Hm, kind of works. But I cannot move it freely, e.g. between `Downloads` and `Home`. It remains a 2nd class bookmark

Answer (score 2):

Or just use *Ubuntu on Xorg* session instead of default Ubuntu ( which is Wayland ).

For me it's a bug → https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/198646

Answer (score 1):

As @coeur-noir mentioned, this seems to be a bug either of wayland or xorg. Here are two screenshot of nautilus places in the same computer, one
[on xorg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXgr7.png) and the other [on wayland](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j15uE.png).

The link that @coeur-noir sent for bugs seems not related to this issue. I tried to find another bug report but I could not. Did I miss something or should we report this bug?

Comment: See [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1875671), [here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/issues/2569), [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333565/ubuntu-21-04-nautilus-sidebar-desktop-icon-is-missing), [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/gnome/comments/qolg4m/why_did_my_desktop_directory_disappear_from_the/), [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1161855/desktop-folder-icon-is-vanished-in-nautilus-sidebar)... I reverted my box to xorg, so I can also restart the desktop manager. If this nonsense continues, I'm seriously thinking to switch to another distro.